# apache2 as proxy to tomcat stopped "proxying"

Tags: proxy, apache2, tomcat7

I followed the documentation

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

and my proxy worked fine.
for some reason it is not working anymore.
I don't see anything in the log file except that it can't find the path (404 for the path that should have been proxied).

can anyone give an idea of what should I check?

(standard apache2 installation on debian 7)

---

my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
AddModule  mod_proxy.c

ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

**my system is debian 7 with debian stock tomcat7.

I don't know why (might be an upgrade issue)

My original proxy configuration that worked was in "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
a file that I've added.

now I moved the configuration to a file that was there from the beginning.

```
"/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

these are the lines I added in the end of apache2.conf:

```
# my proxy
LoadModule  proxy_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so

ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8081/myapp
```